# Where to change minSdkVersion setting in PhoneGap app

Tags: android, cordova

I'm having a strange issue when trying to build a basic PhoneGap app on OS X. The app is setup with just the Android platform. I'm getting the following error when I enter "PhoneGap build".

```
:processDebugManifest
/Volumes/Data/Tests/my-app/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:15:5 Error:

uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 10 declared in library /Volumes/Data/Tests/my-app/platforms/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/android/CordovaLib/unspecified/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage
```

When I then edit the indicated file and set the line to

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion=“10” android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

and build again, the error doesn't change. Does this setting exist somewhere else? Or is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The AndroidManifest.xml file is overwritten during the build process by the values from config.xml. You should define this properties in the config.xml file.

Reference:
http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/configuring_preferences.md.html#Preferences

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
```

Comment: After the cordova build Android command, android-minSdkVersion parameter is still overwritten even though it is defined in config.xml. Any idea why ?

Comment: have that in my config.xml and I am still getting the error 9 cannot be smaller than 10

Comment: I confirm what shamaleyte says. Despite putting minSdkVersion to 10 in every xml file in the unverse, the parameter is set to 14 during the build process. I suspect it might be due to this change: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9428

Comment: The safe way I ended up with is to change all of the config.xml files accourdingly (5 files) that  I found in my project folder. That makes the build successfull.