# Phonegap build error (phonegap build android command)

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to install phonegap and I have some errors in build. (I have already installed jdk, git, node.js , apache-ant, android studion, sdk and sdk manager and set environment variables)

```
:processDebugManifest
C:\my_first_app\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml:15:5 Error:
        uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 10 declared in l
ibrary C:\my_first_app\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\androi
d\CordovaLib\unspecified\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
        Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usag
e


 FAILED



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.

>
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version
 10 declared in library C:\my_first_app\platforms\android\build\intermediates\ex
ploded-aar\android\CordovaLib\unspecified\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
        Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usag
e



* Try:

Run with
--stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
 or --debug
 option to get more log output.



BUILD FAILED




Total time: 47.884 secs


C:\my_first_app\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\my_first_app\platforms\androi
d\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\my_first_app\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.
gradle.daemon=true"

ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Cebit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ph
onegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:1
34:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

In System properties -> Environment variables:

`path` variable is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Silverfrost\FTN95;C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState Komodo IDE 8\;%systemroot%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;%systemroot%\system32\wbem;%systemroot%\system32;c:\progra~2\egcs\bin;c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sql server\100\tools\binn\;c:\program files\microsoft sql server\100\tools\binn\;c:\program files\microsoft sql server\100\dts\binn\;%systemroot%;%QUARTUS_ROOTDIR%\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2010a\runtime\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2010a\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.

**First** of all, there is a problem in new version of phonegap that is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037037/phonegap-create-and-build-commands-fail-due-to-minsdk-version). (Check accepted answer)

**Then** in `www\config.xml` file, replace this:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
```

With this:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.. Thanks for the share.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your error log says you are using uses-sdk:minSdkVersion=7
Change to 10 or better, I recommend 14

```
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion=10
```

It will set your Android SDK level to 10 (Gingerbread).

What is *use-sdk:minSdkVersio*n? Follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Comment: I have already added `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />` to config.xml file in the root, but again the same error. Where should I add yours??

Comment: Sorry, I did not see this until now. In your Error Log it says: ```Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage``` If this does not work, then We should move to the [Phonegap Official forum](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi). Please make sure to mention you are on Windows and mention this thread.

Comment: How should I add `tools:overrideLibrary`? Thanks.

Comment: Finally I found the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @vahid, Can you share the answer so other can benefit? TIA Jesse

Comment: Yes, I wrote it as an answer.