# PhoneGap setting minSDKVersion preference to 10 failing because it still wants 14

Tags: android, xml, cordova

This is the error I'm getting

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
>
> > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 10 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library
> >     /Users/teacher/sites/pg/platforms/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/android/CordovaLib/unspecified/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
> >       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force
> >     usage

And as per [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29978790/where-to-change-minsdkversion-setting-in-phonegap-app) I'm using

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
```

but still getting the complaint for 14. I've tried manually setting every config.xml and AndroidManifest.xml in the .cordova and my project folder folder I can find to use min sdk 10. But when I build, the file it refers to jumps back to being 14. I've been looking for 2 days for a solution but no dice.

Comment: why are you using less than 14 version ?

Comment: latest cordova requires minSdkVersion >= 14, if you want to use version 10 you'll have to use the previous version